# Resize hard drive partition size

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

i have three partitions on my computer which are

- C - 80GB
- D - 166GB
- F - 204GB

I need to increase the C: as to transfer the F partition capacity to C:. Can that be possible and how without rebooting.

Comment: Are these three partitions all on a single hard drive? What operating system is your computer running? (Be as specific as possible.)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible without rebooting, as C: likely contains your operating system (Windows).

Assuming F is empty (or mainly empty), i.e. you can't shrink partitions if they contain data, I'm assuming that 3 partitions are in the same order as the letters, i.e. C: is the first partition, and F: is the last.

So you need to boot (via a CD) into a partition editor to do it, the tool you use *might* have a wizard to do this, but they didn't when I last did this.

The manual steps are:

1. Shrink F: by the amount of space you want to add to C:
2. Move F: to the end of the disk(creating a space between D: and F:)
3. Move D: to be next to F:
4. Expand C: to fill the gap.

Steps 1-3 can be very time consuming if the disk is heavily used and near capacity.
I would recommend running a full defrag on each drive before starting.

An alternative approach: find a usb disk of 500gb or more.  Move contents of D: and F: to it, then you can delete D:, F: partitions and resize C: and then recreate.

[GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/display-doc.php?name=help-manual) is a free partition editor, or there is the commercial [Arconis DiskDirector](http://www.acronis.co.uk/homecomputing/products/diskdirector/).

Comment: Gparted i would only remove F, move D to last position and then grow C. (from 'transfer the F partition capacity' i would assume F is no longer needed). Another funny approach could be to move a large directory from c to f and create a junction to that directory on C

Comment: thanks guys, but F, now is empty D nearly full cause i transfer most of c and all F to D, but still D has 24GB free,

Comment: what do you mean "non of those two works", the apps certainly do work.  I would do what Offler suggested, delete F, shrink and move D to the end and then expand C.

Comment: partition C/is WIN7 can it be expanded?

Comment: to all how assist me, thank you very much, you are great, what it works is i transfer all data from F/ and D/ to an external HD then, delete volume F, add it to D, then delete D, by then i got the permeation to extend C/ so i manage to add 200GB on it now it is awesome to work with Ableton and pro tools and save my work freely. thanks again and GOD Bless, now i dont care cause you are there for me....... good friends...